# How to handle a lot of simple unique URLs (for click's statistics)?

Tags: 7, subsites

I need to create a lot of simple unique URLs (for click's statistics).
Each such URL consist of several parameters (project_name, unique_ID, etc).

Examples:
example.com/project1_id35 or
example.com/project1/id35 or
project1.example.com/id35 ...

I plan to use Rules to decipher these URLs and to save it to database.

But how Drupal site can catch all such URLs?
It's really hard to make aliases for every case.

May be mod_rewrite can help?
Or is there any useful module for such task?

PS. It seems mod_rewrite the best solution.
PPS. Another possible solution: override 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

A great module to aliases auto-generation is [PathAuto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto). It will allow you to define patterns to your url's using tokens, things like:

**article/[title-raw]**

will generate:

**www.example.com/article/my-blog-post**

Once you install the module, go to:

Administration > Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases, in the "Patterns tab" (admin/config/search/path/patterns).

Comment: As I know I can use Pathauto if I have node for every case. But there are no such nodes (and no need it).